# Magento onepage checkout "stuck in place order"

Tags: magento

In my magento project, when i am trying to place order after filling all the details like shipping location, payment method etc, when i am clicking on place order button nothing happens. I searched over google but no solution worked for me.

any idea what should i do.

Comment: You need some debugging here.Inspect in chrome by clicking "f12".On the network see what is the request and response.and check in console tab whether there is some error in js.

Comment: thanks aton for reply, I replaced info.phtml of my theme from the file in base folder and it worked for me.

Comment: These type of errors (i.e. Missing base templates) normally show up in the system.log file for future reference.